# Understanding the (categorical) Calculus of Fractions

Tags: category-theory

Given a category $\mathsf C$ and a class of arrows $\Sigma$, we say the category of fractions $\mathsf C [\Sigma ^{-1}]$  exists when there's a functor $\varphi :\mathsf C \rightarrow \mathsf C [\Sigma ^{-1}]$ that makes any $f\in \Sigma$ into an isomorphism, and is universal with respect to this property, i.e any other functor $F:\mathsf C \rightarrow \mathsf D$ which makes the elements of $\Sigma$ into isomorphisms uniquely factors through $\varphi$.

This definition is simple and makes perfect sense to me, and so does its construction when $\Sigma$ is a set. However, the concept of *(right) calculus of fractions* eludes me completely. Here's the definition given in the first volume of Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra*:

---

[image]

---

***Questions:***

1. What is the idea behind this definition?
2. Why is it called a calculus of fractions?

Comment: The point, as it were, is to have Propositions 5.2.4 and 5.2.5.

Comment: This gives an explicit, simpler description of $\mathsf{C}[\Sigma^{-1}]$ than the usual one. "Calculus of fractions" comes from the similarity with the fraction field of an integral domain.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: In the first paragraph, it should be "any functor $F \colon \mathsf C \to \mathsf D$ **mapping the elements of $\Sigma$ to isomorphisms** uniquely factors through $\varphi$".

Comment: @Pece yes of course. I'll correct it.

Comment: I don't have a copy of Borceux with me, but the idea behind the definition is to require what is necessary to build a category equivalent (actually isomorphic) to $\mathsf C[\Sigma^{-1}]$. You can look at the beginning of chapter I.2 of _Calculus of fractions and homotopy theory_ from Gabriel and Zisman.

Comment: Stenstrom's http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-66066-5 book develops a theory of localization for one-object $\mathbf{Ab}$-categories, or, in the old fashioned jargon, "rings".